# Compiling DCMTK for Android get CMake Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, dcmtk

I am use cmake DCMTK for Android

OS    : Win7 64bit

DCMTK : dcmtk-3.6.0

CMake : cmake-3.7.0-rc3

NDK   : android-ndk-r9d

I followed the dcmtk wiki
http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_CompileAndroid 
get CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

but i have already set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
[here is my CMake set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkFeL.jpg)

but does not work

Please help me